# How to export json from iteratively created dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to export dataframes that are iteratively created based on the column value. The idea is that I would use both the column value to dictate the folder as well as filtering the dataframe.

In order to create the dataframes iteratively I'm using `exec()`. The example follows below. The idea would be to be able to run iteratively the creation of `df.to_json('dfName/'+datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')+'.json')` where the `dfName` would change iteratively to `a`, `b`, `c`. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate I didn't seem to find anything of sorts so far

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

data1 = ['a', 'a', 'a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
data2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
data3 = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]

data = {
        'Name':data1,
        'data2':data2,
        'data3':data3}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


for test in df.Name.unique():
    exec(test + "=df[df['Name'] == test]")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without filters using `groupby()`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

data1 = ['a', 'a', 'a','b','b','b','c','c','c']
data2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
data3 = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]

data = {
        'Name':data1,
        'data2':data2,
        'data3':data3}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for name, n_df in df.groupby('Name'):
    # do what you need... n_df.to_csv() etc...
    print(name)
    print(n_df)
```