# Best way of reading a large dataset and dividing it into seperate files by a specific column with IDs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I'm trying to read large dataset (over 6GB with over 20 columns) into pandas dataframe.
The data looks like this (but divided with tabs instead of commas):

```
0,   -1,  -1, [...], 52FC53D2C1C2, C27BFF0305
1, 30.0, 200, [...], FB490491C2F7, DA55A029E7
1, 20.0, 192, [...], 52FC53D2C1C2, 5E3822B0E0
0,   -1,  -1, [...], 9702BF6338D3, 7D1FB49049
```

The second last column is an ID (not unique)that I need the dataset to be divided by into smaller, seperate files.
For example:

```
# File 1
0,   -1,  -1, [...], 52FC53D2C1C2, C27BFF0305
1, 20.0, 192, [...], 52FC53D2C1C2, 5E3822B0E0

# File 2
1, 30.0, 200, [...], FB490491C2F7, DA55A029E7

# File 3
0,   -1,  -1, [...], 9702BF6338D3, 7D1FB49049
```

What I tried to do was to read the dataset to a dataframe with pandas.read_csv.

```
colnames = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", [...], "ID", "zzz"]
data = pd.read_csv(path, engine='python', header=None, names=colnames, sep=r'\t')
```

Then I tried to get unique IDs by using .unique option of DataFrame, search for lines with the specific ID and then export them to a seperate csv files.

```
unique_ids = data['ID'].unique()
unique_ids = unique_ids.tolist()
for i, val in enumerate(unique_ids):
    data[data['ID'] == val].to_csv(os.path.join(path + 'ID' + str(val) + '.csv'),
                                           index=False, na_rep='N/A')
```

I tested it on a smaller sample and it worked fine, but doing it on a full dataset takes forever.
Is there any way in pandas or maybe other library to read and process the file much faster?
Thanks!

Comment: [JFYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75448055/how-to-export-json-from-iteratively-created-dataframes-in-pandas/75448096#75448096). You can do it without filters and iteration.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Thanks! Will try it, but the dataset still needs to be somehow read which I think is the main performance problem there. I've read that Dask may be better at handling large files so I'll try it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read your file by chunks and use `groupby` to write data:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

CHUNKSIZE = 10000
DATA_DIR = pathlib.Path('.')

colnames = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ID", "zzz"]
for chunk in pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR / 'data.csv', sep='\t', chunksize=CHUNKSIZE, header=None, names=colnames):
    for ID, df in chunk.groupby('ID'):
        file = DATA_DIR / f'ID{ID}.csv'
        df.to_csv(file, mode='a', header=not file.exists(), na_rep='N/A', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and compare its performance with Dask library's read_csv as I've read it could be more efficient for handling large files.